# Aborted during update (16.04) - file retrieval help

Tags: login, files, data-recovery

I, being an idiot, manually aborted during a software update as I had stupidly left things running and the computer froze.

Now when I enter my password on the user account, the screen scrambles. On the guest log-in, there is nothing but blue. I can wave my mouse around. But no sidebar, no ability to open programs, nothing.

Evidently I broke it. I presume that one of the things I was downloading and installing was key to the whole functionality deal.

I think a full re-install is needed and that's on me. However I have some files on there that I very much need to retrieve. I've seen a friend of mine retrieve files from a knackered old PC of mine 10 years ago so I know it can be done.

Comment: Boot from the LiveUSB (you must create one anyway for the clean-install). Select 'Try Ubuntu'. Mount your HDD. Copy your files from your HDD to some other safe media.

Comment: thanks. sorted. installed 18.04 and partitioned, files still there. backed up. installed again over everything.

Comment: Actually, you can resume a broken upgrade process. I had to do it a couple of times and I was too lazy to reinstall. :P But gladly you sorted it out. Please do not write solutions in comments, write a self-answer instead. ;)